# Why basic C code throws Access violation

Tags: c, exception

I am new to C programming. I am trying to learn it. Following code throws Access violation. Why is it happening? Please explain it. How to fix it?

```
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
printf("%s", arr[0]);
```

Comment: `%s` is for `char *`. Use `%c` specification for `char` data type.

Comment: `'a'` is the integer value 97, so you're telling it to print as a string whatever it finds at memory address 97, which may or may not be a valid address, and even if it is, would have random contents.

Comment: I forgot to add,  `%s` is for null terminated `char *` data type.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker on most modern desktops the entire zero page (the first 4k of VM) is mapped as no-access as to trigger this sort of result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
printf("%c", arr[0]);
```

%s says print all the characters until you find a null (treat the variable as a pointer).

%c says print just one character (treat the variable as a character code)

Using %s for a character doesn't work because the character is going to be treated like a pointer, then it's going to try to print all the characters following that place in memory until it finds a null.

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` means to print a C-string, and `'a'` is not a C string, but a character, that's what the single quotes delimit.

What ends up happening is your `arr` is interpreted as a C string, but as it's not properly NUL terminated the program walks off the end and into invalid memory, triggering your error.

The fix is to use either `%c` to print a single character, or to terminate the array:

```
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

%s is for char * i.e. 'C - string' which require null termination. In your code as null character is missing you get the error as further memory location are being accessed looking for NULL character.

```
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0' };
printf("%s", &arr[0]);
```

Comment: You still need the pointer, not the value (i.e. `&arr[0]` or just `arr`).

Comment: My mistake, it was an typographical mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` format specifier expects an `char *` (char pointer) as input whichs points to the beginning of an nullterminated character array.

The `arr` itself can be treated as pointer to first element.
Which means `char arr[ <size> ]` is seen as `char * const arr`.
The difference is `sizeof(arr)` in the first example returns the actual size (in bytes) of the array.

**Possible solutions**

```
char arr1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], arr1[3], arr1[4], arr1[5]); /*please don't do this*/
printf("%*s\n", sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]), arr1); /*prints exact amount of characters*/
char arr2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0'};
printf("%s\n", arr2); /*explicit null termination*/
char arr3[] = "abcdef";
printf("%s\n", arr3); /*implicit null termination with string literal*/
const char *arr4 = "abcdef";
printf("%s\n", arr3); /*implicit null termination with string literal and pointertype*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` conversion specifier expects the corresponding argument to have type `char *` and to contain the *address* of the first character in a 0-terminated string.  You're getting the access violation because `'a'` (ASCII 97) is not a valid address.

If you want to print the single character `a`, use the `%c` conversion specifier instead:

```
printf( "%c\n", arr[0] );
```

If you want to print the *string* contained in `arr`, first you have to add the terminator:

```
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 0 }; // or "abcdef";
```

then use the `%s` conversion specifier and pass `arr` as follows:

```
printf( "%s\n", arr ); // or &arr[0], which does the same thing
```